# Can a relation be in 3NF with multiple foreign keys?

Tags: database, normalization

I think this is pretty basic, but I am new to this. I am trying to normalize a table. Can a relation be 3NF with multiple foreign keys? Is this 3NF:

- TALENTPAYMENT (PAYMENTNUMBER, date, subtotal, tax, total, talentid, agentnumber)

or would it need to be broken down more to:

- TALENTPAYMENT (PAYMENTNUMBER, date, subtotal, tax, total)
- TALENTPAYMENTID (PAYMENTNUMBER, talentid)
- TALENTAGENT (TALENTID, agentnumber)

Answer (score 3):

I think most of the other answers are more oriented toward your example than toward your question.

To speak directly to the question, yes, a relation can be in 3NF even if it has multiple foreign keys. The key (cough) point of 3NF is to remove transitive dependencies, not to reduce the number of foreign keys.

To put it another way, there's no such thing as "I have too many foreign keys" normal form.

Answer (score 2):

It's not 3NF, but not because of your foreign keys. You have some functional dependencies of which the left side is not a candidate key:

```
subtotal,tax   -> total
subtotal,total -> tax
tax,total -> subtotal
```

The algorithm for reducing to 3NF would say to split your schema into:

`PAYMENTNUMBER | date | subtotal | tax | talentid | agentnumber`

and

`subtotal | tax | total`

At which point, assuming "talentid -> agentnumber" or the reverse are not dependencies, the schema is in 3NF, but your (subtotal, tax, total) table is basically useless since storing all three an obvious redunancy. It would be better just to use:

`PAYMENTNUMBER | date | subtotal | tax | talentid | agentnumber`

And not store total at all. If you want it in a query you can just `SELECT (subtotal+tax) as total` assuming subtotal and tax are both numeric types.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in 3NF anyway since total = subtotal + tax (or the other way around; I'm bad at the difference between total and subtotal).

To be in 3NF, you must not have transitive functional dependencies with non-prime attributes. Eliminate the derived attribute (total or subtotal) and I believe your solution is A OK.

For that matter, the original might be OK, but for the problem I mention.

Answer (score 0):

Your three part schema suggests that there might be a functional dependency *talentid* ⟶ *agentnumber*, in which case your relation cannot be in BCNF (3NF) because *talendtid* is not one of the keys for the relation.

On the other hand, talent/agent relationships tend to be fragile, so it would not be surprising to find that the same talent is represented by different agents at different times.  In that case, you probably need to keep the 'agent of the talent at the time of the payment' on record, and your original schema is better than the three-part one (because changes in the data of the three-part scheme changes historical records).